# Every http protocol in wireshark-captured packets are ssl encrypted

Tags: http, ssl, wireshark

I used to get packets in wireshark, where http protocols were not encrypted but recently every packet with application data in my wireshark captured packets is ssl encrypted. There is not even one packet where I can see http protocol. Its TLsv1.1 and the data is encrypted. So basically I cannot see the header information. Can anyone reply as to why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: What are the source and destination ports of those SSL packets?

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to the same question asked on the Wireshark Q&A site](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/22487/all-the-http-protocol-packets-captured-are-ssl-protected).  (Summary: at least one of the ports in question is 443, as I suspected, so you're either going to an https:// URL or somebody's redirecting your traffic to an https:// URL.)